# RailsTutorial.org - ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and in the second chapter, a demo app is setup. I am up against an error and I am not able to find the cause!!

I made sure that I followed every command that was in the tutorial:

1. Ran `rails new to demo_app` create the project
2. Updated the gem file as was required
3. Executed `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`
4. Migrated the DB using `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
5. Started the server - `rails s`
6. `http://localhost:3000/` shows up right
7. When I try to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/users/`, I am presented with this error

[image]

Can anybody shed some light on why the setup is acting up?!

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: windows 8.1 and if it helps - the app didn't run in chrome, firefox and ie

Comment: u need javascript runtime, just install node.js

Answer (score 1):

> steps to   Install Node.js

`Go to` [nodejs website](http://nodejs.org) `and download the installer`

```
    Click on the downloaded file to run the install wizard. Click Next at each step to accept the defaults.

    Reboot your computer.

    Once your computer is back up, load Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails OR simple command prompt and...
    Type this in the terminal:    


     node -v
```