# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails web application I am getting error below:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users#new

Showing C:/Sites/VideoResume/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:


  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-1.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
```

[image]

Kindly suggest me, How do I resolve it.
Waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: Is `rake assets:precompile` working for you?
Do you have *gem 'therubyracer'* in you Gemfile?

Comment: no but I was try to install `therubyracer`, then I am getting some more issues , that's why I remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when running rails app - ExecJS::RuntimeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing `nodejs`. First do that it should solve the problem.
[How to Install Nodejs on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302436/install-nodejs-on-ubuntu-12-10)

some helpful links and possible duplicates are

[ExecJS::RuntimeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror)

[ExecJS::RuntimeError NodeJS Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827958/railstutorial-org-execjsruntimeerror-in-usersindex)

Comment: I have install node.js and when I check this command `node -v` on Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails then it show me `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: if it has been installed then it means that nodejs has not been added to your system path.

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: what is the path of your nodejs installation. where did you install nodejs ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: @user88 try SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH% in command prompt and then try running node

Comment: use this link and add the above given path to PATH environment variable `http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml` . another thing if you have installed nodejs from windows binary it would have already added it to PATH try restarting the command prompt also. 

you can also use  user2675613's solution but to do it permanently you will have to use method i mentioned

Comment: now try `node -v` if you have added the path successfully it should work now .

Comment: yes it show me the version on windows command prompt, but `ExecJS::RuntimeError` still come on the browser, How do I resolve it

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [github link](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) given above therubyracer gem in your new rails app. It says

`ExecJS lets you run JavaScript code from Ruby. It automatically picks the best runtime available to evaluate your JavaScript program, then returns the result to you as a Ruby object.`

**ExecJS supports these runtimes:**

- therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby
- therubyrhino - Mozilla Rhino embedded within JRuby
- Node.js
- Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X
- Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript)

**Fix**

You could solve it by installing any of these runtimes.

You can checkout [therubyracer_for_windows](https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows) someone recommended it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181526/is-there-a-way-of-installing-therubyracer-in-windows) or checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)